# Change background drawable for all layouts

Tags: android, android-studio, background

Is there a way to change the background image of all screen layouts?

Yes I understand you can do it for each one individually by using

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.score_view);
linearLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue));
```

But is there a way to change the drawable for all .xml layout files like maybe changing the drawable name?  Or creating a custom class?

Comment: add the background attribute to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<item name="android:windowBackground">@[Your background]</item>` in your application theme to change complete backgroud of you application.